# Evaluate: $\sum_{k=2}^n {n!\over (n-k)!(k-2)!}$

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate:

$$\sum_{k=2}^n {n!\over (n-k)!(k-2)!}$$

Efforts:

To be honest, I just played with the expression, but I don't know how to approach it.

Take $n=2$,

we get $2!$

Take $n=3$, we get

${3!\over 1!0!}+ {3!\over 0!1!}$

Take $n=4$

we get ${4!\over 2!0!}+ {4!\over 1!1!}+ {4!\over 0!2!}$

Take $n=5$, we get ${5!\over 3!0!}+ {5!\over 2!1!}+{5!\over 1!2!}+{5!\over 0!3!}$

So this is what I have observed,

for each $n$, we have $n!$ in the denominator. And in denominator, we have terms like $a!b!$ such that $a+b=n-k$

Example in case of $N=6$ we have $6!$ in numerator. In denominator we have terms like $4!0!, 3!1!, 2!2!, 1!3!, 0!4!$

but how does that help. There is clearly a pattern in how the denominator appears but does that help in some way?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(k-2\right)!}=n\left(n-1\right)\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n-2}{k-2}=n\left(n-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}=n\left(n-1\right)2^{n-2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You may procced as follows:

- $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}=\binom{n}{k} \cdot k(k-1)$
- $[(1+x)^n]'' = \sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\cdot k(k-1)x^{k-2}$

It follows

$$n(n-1)2^{n-2} =n(n-1)(1+1)^{n-2} = \sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\cdot k(k-1) = \sum_{k=2}^n {n!\over (n-k)!(k-2)!}$$